# Hairy Ball Theorem: conceptual difficulty

Tags: soft-question, differential-topology

I am still having lot of difficulty in understanding the Hairy Ball Theorem. Even though, I saw these two beautiful answers [Hairy Ball theorem and its applications](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6431/hairy-ball-theorem-and-its-applications), [The Hairy ball theorem and Möbius transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626465/the-hairy-ball-theorem-and-m%C3%B6bius-transformations), but couldn't get my answer. I was and still now wondering, why the fields have to vanish at one(or more) point(for even sphere $S^{2k}$)? Or why such a point exist where they have to vanish?

Not actually proof but a proper justification in simple words will suffice.

**P.S.** :Forgive me for my ignorance, even I don't know that this a proper question to ask? Any point near to it will equally help. Please let me know where I am thinking or going wrong.

Comment: You want a proof of the theorem? Try this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90737/shortest-proof-for-hairy-ball-theorem

Comment: @A.Sh Not actually proof but a justification(if can be given in words)

Comment: @user60589 lol. I think it applies, just the point of my question. I really hope you will get it , what I am saying.

Comment: @L.K. Sorry for that. I like this [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/90741)

Comment: @user60589 But still my ignorance is very high, though. Why the fields have to vanish at all at one(or more) point(for even sphere)? Is there some deeper intuition or reason behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a differential geometric proof. To me it is quite intuitive, since it not uses so much topology, despite the fact that the identity on $\Bbb S^1$ is not contractible. I am not totally convinced that this works, but if so, maybe someone has a reference for me?

You could use the stereographic projection where you remove the north pole. For a vector field $F'$ on the sphere there is a corresponding vector field $F$ on $\Bbb R^2$,

The vector field $F$ can be assumed to be normalized. Then for any $r>0$ you get a self map $F_r$ of $\Bbb S^1$ which is the composition
$$ \Bbb S^1 \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^2 \xrightarrow{\cdot r} \Bbb{R}^2 \xrightarrow{F}  \Bbb S^1 \subset \Bbb{R}^2.$$

Since $F$ is continuous for sufficiently small $r>0$ the map $F_r$ is contractible.

If we now show that for sufficiently large $r$ this map is homotopic to the identity, this is a contradiction, since the identity on one-sphere is not null homotopic.

In order to do this we have to take a look at the stereographic projection who the tangent vectors are mapped.

The stereographic projection with north pole removed is given by
$$ P_N (x,y,z) = \frac{1}{1-z} (x ,y ) $$
and its Jacobian matrix is
$$ 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \frac{1}{1-z} & 0 & \frac{x}{(1-z)^2}   \\
        0 &  \frac{1}{1-z} & \frac{y}{(1-z)^2}  \\
        \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Using partitions of unity we can assume that in a small neighborhood of $N$ the vector field $F'$ is given by $F'(x,y,z)=(0,-z,y)$.

Using the Jacobian matrix we know that for large $r$ the corresponding vector field $F$ on $\Bbb R^2$ is given by
$$  F(P_N(x,y,z)) =  \left(  \frac{xy}{(1-z)^2} , \frac{y^2}{(1-z)^2}-  \frac{z}{1-z}  \right) . $$
composing with the inverse of the stereographic projection
$$  P_N^{-1}(x,y) = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} ( 2x, 2y, x^2+y^2-1) $$
we get
$$ F(x,y) =   (4xy, 3 y^2 -x^2 +1 ). $$
Switching to to polar coordinates we get
$$ F(\varphi, r)  = r^2 \left( 4 \cos \varphi \sin \varphi, 3 \sin^2 \varphi -\cos^2 \varphi + \frac{1}{r^2}  \right) = r^2( 2  \sin (2\varphi), 1- 2\cos (2 \varphi) + \frac{1}{r^2}  ) .  $$
For big $r$ this defines a circle. So $F_r$ has a non zero mapping degree, in fact it is homotopic to the identity.

This completes the proof.

**Edit:**

Here is some more intuitive argument. Imagine you have a vector field F on S2 ⊂ R3 given on the equator in the x-y-plane by F (x, y, z) = (y, −x, 0). Pictorially this are vectors which ”move” around the circle. Now if you move the plane to the south pole you can look how these vectors rotate. To make this more precise you could project the tangent vectors to the x-y-plane. For a fixed angle in the x-y-plane when you move down the z-axis to the south pole, the projected tangent vector has to rotate into the direction of the tangent vector at south pole. Now what is the problem? The projection maps only zero vectors to zero, since on the x-y-plane the vector field was assumed to be non-vanishing. So if you go down the z-axis, all tangent vectors on points parallel to the x-y-plane will turn to the same direction, but this can not be unless you have a zero or a discontinuity at some point.

It think this is quite intuitive. What is the ”problem” with that? In the prove before I made a local assumption, which is easy to make. But here I made a huge restriction by fixing the vector field on the equator.

Now I claim this is not as bad as it might looks. Here is a recipe how you can turn it into an almost proof. Take a non vanishing tangent field F , then approximate it by an smooth tangent field. Now you need to find one integral curve which gives you a loop on the sphere. Then choose a point inside but not on the curve and take it as south pole. Then with small perturbations ensure that the tangent field does not vanish when projected to the plane though equator. Having this you can proceed as before.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the Hairy Ball Theorem is what I like to think of as a "Weird Fact" - the best justification that can be given is the proof itself. In other words, I don't know of any really good intuitive explanation of the theorem. I'll give it a crack anyway. To be clear, I'm not trying to prove anything; user60589 gave a perfectly good proof already.

Concentrate on the $2$-sphere (so, a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$), because that's the one we can visualize. Imagine a unit tangent vector field on it. Starting from the north pole and moving south, the vector must turn to match the surface; as we move through the south pole and back to the north pole, the vector has to perform at least one complete $360^\circ$ rotation. In doing this, we traversed a circle; imagine rotating that circle on its axis, so that it continues to pass through the poles but the rest of the circle moves. As this circle rotates $180^\circ$, the vectors along it must switch directions (because one half of the circle is trading places with the other half). But, intuitively, the vectors "wasted" one degree of freedom in order to turn around *along* the circle, so they only have one more degree of freedom with which to make this switch. That means that the Intermediate Value Theorem kicks in - in order to move from one direction to the opposite, they have to pass through zero. The reason we only need *one* zero point is because the others can sort of "squeeze" themselves so that the zero guaranteed by IVT shows up at the same point on the sphere for all of them.

Again, this is not a proof - it's not even very solid reasoning. But in my opinion it's a pretty good intuition for why the Hairy Ball Theorem is true on the $2$-sphere.